# How to test if serializable object exists in storage before reading from it?

Tags: java, android, storage, serializable

I have an object Data which I have made serializable. When my main activity loads I want it to check whether there is a saved instance of Data in storage. If so, to read it and instantiate as a variable. If not, a new copy of Data will be used.

My code for reading and writing the object:

```
 // Method used to read questions data
    public static void read(){
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream in = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("SAVED_DATA");
            in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            myData = (Data) in.readObject();
            in.close();;
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();;
        }
    }
    // Method used to write the questions data
    public static void save(){
         FileOutputStream fos = null;
         ObjectOutputStream out = null;
         try{
             fos = new FileOutputStream("SAVED_DATA");
             out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
             out.writeObject(myData);
         } catch (Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
```

My code within my onCreate() method will be something like:

```
if (read()) { //How to test if a Data object exists?
read(); // Read the object from storage and set variable to the result
       } else {
           myData = new Data(); // There's no stored object so set up a new one
   }
```

What is the best (simplest) way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't catch the `IOException`. Let it be thrown. Or return a value that indicates success or failure.

Comment: I like the idea of returning a value indicating success of failure - how would I work that into my read() method and combine it with my if statement?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved this use case by amending my read() method as follows:

```
 // Method used to read questions data
    public static void read(File path){
        ObjectInputStream in = null;
        String filename = "SAVED_DATA";
        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(new File(path, "")+File.separator+filename)));
            myData = (Data) in.readObject();
            in.close();;
            Log.i("dev", "just closed the stream, read successful");
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.i("dev", "exception with read - about to set to defaul object");
            Log.e("dev", "exception", e);

            myData = new Data();
        }
    }
```

If the read is successful then the object read from storage is used, if there's an error then it uses a fresh one :)

Then simply call read() in the oncreate() method.